# XCode - How can you change where xcode looks for a folder

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently my app can't build. I think this is because XCode is looking for my "Library" folder in a place that it is not in. This folder got moved because of the new Yosemite update. Please if someone knows the answer, post the answer!

Here is an image of the error that shows when I try to build.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGnOD.jpg

Comment: Maybe it would help if you said what error is being reported in the build log.

Comment: An update to Yosemite does not move the Library folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can always remove and add again the libraries in such case, without wasting any time for looking up for path or location for the them.

In case you haven't them backed up locally, you can have it again from [BoltsFramewrok GitHub link](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS).

Comment: Agree. Also, creating pod for such kind of project is always useful.